# Expected value uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Can you help me with this exercise? Let $N$ a random variable discrete with $P(N=i)=1/n$, to $i=\lbrace a+b,a+2b,...,a+nb\rbrace$ with $a$,$b$ real and $n$ positive integer. Calculate $E[N]$, $V(N)$.

I tried this, but I don't know if that is correct:

$$E(N)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(a+ib)}{n}=\frac{2a+bn+b}{2}$$

Comment: Get variance via $E(N^2).$ There is a formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easy way to do this is to let $X$ be integer on $1,2,...,n$ and find its mean and variance, then let $N=a+bX$ and use elementary properties of means and [variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties).

$E(X^2) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ is straightforward.